# Prevent ContextMenu on ListViewItem from disappearing when changing Filter

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, listviewitem

I have a ListView and TextBox for entering search text.

When the user searches for some text, I start a long-running search operation (on the UI thread, through a UI-thread-timer), and every now and again, while the search is still active, I change the `ICollectionView.Filter`  property, to cause the ListView to refresh and present more items that the search has found as matching.

The problem is that if the user right clicks on one of the items, and then as Search is happening in the background, the tree is refreshed, then the ContextMenu disappears.

How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: What are you trying to prevent: the tree from refreshing OR the ContextMenu from disappearing?

Comment: The context menu from disappearing

Comment: @Omer Raviv: I think you'll need to add some sample code. I tried to reproduce your problem but I couldn't get the `ContextMenu` to close when changing the filter no matter what I did or wherever I placed the `ContextMenu`. For me, on XP, it stays open

Comment: Is the whole tree refreshed or just the new items added to the end of the list?

Comment: The whole tree is being refreshed

Answer (score 1):

Here's my theory:
Because the whole tree is refreshed, WPF cannot know that the item (which was right-clicked) is the exact same item as after the refresh.  Technically, that Item isn't even "there" anymore.  It's really a new item with the exact same properties (from the ListView's perspective).

There are a some ways you can try to remediate this:

- Capture the right-click of the item, store the item; capture the tree refresh, check if the item is equal to the stored item; if equal show the ContextMenu.
- Instead of refreshing the whole tree, add items to the end of the list.
- While ContextMenu is open, suspend refreshing the tree.

Comment: Personally, I'd try the 2nd (don't know if filtering will be applied correctly with adding items as opposed to refreshing (don't know why it _wouldn't_)).  If that doesn't work, try the 3rd.  Finally, try the 1st.